# Android Java Custom view can not keep value passed from activity

Tags: java, android, canvas, view

I am tring to pass value from Main Activity to Custom View, I created a `setColor` metod in the CustomView. Inside the `setColor` metod it output the right value, but the outside the value is not changed, method doesn't effect the variable. Please help me with this problem.

MainActivity create CustomView `canvas` and send data by `canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK)`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    com.example.myapplication.MyCanvas myCanvas;
    View test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //test = findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas(this, null);
        canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

CustomView `canvas`

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {
   public int test;
   public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
   }
   public void setColor(int color) {
      this.test = color;
      Log.e("test", "setColor " + test);
   }
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      Log.e("test", "Color " + test);
   }
}
```

Output of `Log.e`

```
2022-02-28 20:06:40.714 29704-29704/com.example.myapplication E/test: setColor -16777216
2022-02-28 20:06:42.314 29704-29704/com.example.myapplication E/test: Color 0
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">

    <com.example.myapplication.MyCanvas
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="501dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="158dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do the log say when you call `canvas.invalidate()` after `canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK)`?

Comment: Hi, it still has the same problem as before. Inside the `setColor()` metod has the correct value, but  `onDraw()` metod still output 0.

Comment: @Fusera you are making mistake with canvas, if you have a canvas in XML, then why should you create a new canvas and setColor to on it.

Comment: @EAS As you said, I tried to use the XML canvas and it works.  This problem has trouble me for quite a long time, thank you for helping me to figure out.